# 403 Error returned when I call an endpoint from python - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python-requests, python-3.6

I have signed up for and been provided all of the details for a store locator API Key against my User ID from Walgreens.

When I run the code below in python (with the relevant private cred's) I get a 403 code saying affId is missing.

The following is sample code from the API docs - located here: https://developer.walgreens.com/sites/default/files/v1_StoreLocatorAPI.html#SearchZipcode

```
request POST \
--url https://services-qa.walgreens.com/api/stores/search/v1 \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{ \
    "apiKey":"YOUR_API_KEY", \
    "affId":"YOUR_AFFILIATE_ID", \
    "zip": CUSTOMER_ZIPCODE, \
    "r": RADIUS_MILES, \
    "filterOptions": FILTER_OPTIONS_ARRAY, \
    "requestType": "locator"
}
```

The following is my attempt to create a call to the endpoint URL with the relevant parameters less my cred's code from the API docs:

**Python Code**

```
import requests
#define variables
urlws = 'https://services-qa.walgreens.com/api/stores/search/v1'
waid = 'USERID'
wapikey = 'APIKEY'
waslid = 'storesapi' 
wazip = '60000' #store zip code
war = '25' #radius of store in miles
rtype = 'locator'
#header 'Content-Type: application/json'

data = {'affId': waid, 
        'apiKey': wapikey, 
        'r': war, 
        'zip': wazip, 
        'requestType': rtype}

r = requests.get(urlws, params=data)

r
```

**Response Received**
{
                "errCode":"403",
                "apiKey":"",
                "errMsg":"Key doesn't Exists" 
            }

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

I'm new to python and requests.

TIA for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the format is JSON and you must use a post. An example.

```
import requests


response = requests.post('https://services-qa.walgreens.com/api/stores/search/v2', json={"apiKey":"Yourkey", "affId":"storesapi","address": "store address", "r":" 0", "s": "1", "requestType": "locator", "appVer":"1.0", "devInf":"DEVICE,##.#" })

print(response.url)
print(response.text)
```